# timerfd windows equivalent

Tags: c, sockets, timer

Is there a timerfd equivalent on windows in C? For example i would like to convert this piece of code with a socket.

**timerfd_settime(timer->ev.sock, 0, &timeout, NULL);**

```
static int timer_start(void *this_ptr, uint64_t timeout_ns, timer_handler handler, void *handler_context)
{
    struct cjet_timer *timer = (struct cjet_timer *)this_ptr;
    timer->handler = handler;
    timer->handler_context = handler_context;

    struct itimerspec timeout = convert_timeoutns_to_itimerspec(timeout_ns);
    return timerfd_settime(timer->ev.sock, 0, &timeout, NULL);
}
```

Thanks!